# How can you get the HttpMethod from the System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

How can you get the HttpMethod from the System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext ? 
The HttpMethod property of the HostedHttpContext 
`(System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpContext)` is `Internal`

**Update - Explanation:**

I have created a `BasicAuthenticationInterceptor` (*inherits* RequestInterceptor) to use for Basic HTTP Authentication in my REST WCF service.
In the `void ProcessRequest(ref RequestContext requestContext)` method, I need to check the **HTTP Method** (e.g. if it is a **POST**)

Comment: Why do you need it?  It may help to explain what you're trying to do a little more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message should have a property of type `HttpRequestMessageProperty` (whose key is `HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name`. Try querying the request message from the context, then fetch that property from the message. The property has the HTTP verb used in the request.

Comment: used: (HttpRequestMessageProperty)message.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name]